# Dimension of a skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose we have 
S={M is 3x3 skew symmetric matrix with the sun of entries of each row is zero} then the dim is 1.
After doing what we have to do, we will end up with only three repeated things in our matrix: 0 a and -a. Okay in that case we know that the number of elements is the dimension, so the dim should be 2 at not 1! Any explanation?

Comment: The "we know that the number of elements is the dimension" part is difficult to understand. Can you explain what it means?

Comment: The theorem says that any two bases for the vector space V will have the same number of elements. This number is called dimension of V denoted by dim V

Comment: and not the mxn dimension :)

Comment: what are your 2 elements?

Comment: well a and -a, 0 is not to consider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ is a vector space of matrices, so a basis is a collection of matrices. In our case, every element of $S$ has the form
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}0&a&-a\\-a&0&a\\a&-a&0
\end{pmatrix}
=
a \begin{pmatrix}0&1&-1\\-1&0&1\\1&-1&0
\end{pmatrix} = a M_0
$$
it follows that the family $B = \{M_0\}$ is a basis and $S$ has dimension $1$.

Comment: Oh so if we had a and b we would have had two matrices Mo and M1, the dimension is 2 in this case right?

Comment: Yes exactly, the space of matrices having the form $\begin{pmatrix}0&a&-b\\-a&0&a\\a&-a&0\end{pmatrix}$ has dimension 2.